# Pandas to_csv drops values

Tags: python, pandas

I ran into an issue where pandas.to_csv drops values on columns of datetime64 type.

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 28982 entries, 0 to 28981
Data columns (total 4 columns):
value    28982  non-null values
date1    28982  non-null values
date2    22772  non-null values
date3    28982  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](3), float64(1)

In [25]: df.tail()
Out[25]: 
       value               date1               date2               date3
28977  25.44 2002-08-21 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00 2007-09-01 00:00:00
28978  25.86 2002-08-21 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00 2007-09-01 00:00:00
28979  26.08 2002-08-21 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00 2007-09-01 00:00:00
28980  25.84 2002-08-21 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00 2007-09-01 00:00:00
28981  25.35 2002-08-21 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00 2007-09-01 00:00:00

In [26]: df.to_csv('test.csv', index = False)

In [27]: df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header = 0)

In [28]: df2
Out[28]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 28982 entries, 0 to 28981
Data columns (total 4 columns):
value    28982  non-null values
date1    28982  non-null values
date2    21070  non-null values
date3    17036  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), object(3)

In [29]: df2.tail()
Out[29]: 
       value                date1 date2 date3
28977  25.44  2002-08-21 00:00:00   NaN   NaN
28978  25.86  2002-08-21 00:00:00   NaN   NaN
28979  26.08  2002-08-21 00:00:00   NaN   NaN
28980  25.84  2002-08-21 00:00:00   NaN   NaN
28981  25.35  2002-08-21 00:00:00   NaN   NaN
```

As shown, I wrote df to file and immediately read it back into df2, the columns date2 and date3 in the csv file have a lot of missing values towards the bottom. Is this a bug?
By the way I am using Pandas 0.11.

Comment: It doesn't happen in my computer, can provide the example csv file?

Comment: Ironically, to_csv drops the values while saving to csv. So the example file would have the values missing already.

Comment: How about dump it by pickle?

Comment: I uploaded it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1aq02njpw1tg97x/test.p

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot of helping to look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3062

workaround is basically this:

```
for c in datetime_columns_that_have_NaT:

     df[c] = df[c].astype('object')

df.to_csv()
```

when you read it back if you specifiy parse_dates=[that_column_num]

it will work

alternatively, you can write like you are and then read like this:

```
dfc = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0).convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')
```

will force date conversion

Comment: sorry but I think my issue is different from the issue you refer to. My issue is that to_csv is not writing values to the csv file. If I open the csv file with a text editor, the values are missing. Your issue refers to read_csv not parsing columns with NaN/NaT, but my issue is to_csv not writing values.

Comment: ok....this is a bug, I can tell you how to fix it (1-line change) if you want to edit the code, it only affects if you have a big frame

Comment: try this to fix it (you can just make the code change inline if you want): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3438

Comment: alternatively you can do:  df.to_csv('a.csv',engine='python')
to use the original to_csv writer

Comment: @Jeff TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine' (python 3.6)

Comment: @Jeff I have the same issue at ezbentley and the same error as Christof Henkel